# loading a multipage file in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have two separate html file that are being loaded via ajax using jquery/jquery mobile framework. But when I load the second file, it only loads the first div the the role of page. Any way to work around this?

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand exactly what you're working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design. When [linking a multipage document use `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

> It's important to note that if you are linking from a mobile page that
>   was loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages,
>   you need to add a **rel="external" or data-ajax="false"** to the link.
>   This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the
>   Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash
>   (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the
>   hash to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash
>   between these two modes.

```
<a href="multipage.html" rel="external">Multi-page link</a>
```

If changing pages programmatically use

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.changePage("multipage.html");
```