# Jquery Mobile - How to load a multi-page html page via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, web

[image: Diagram of the page transitions]

I got a intricate problem with jquery-mobile loading a multi-page page (a page with several  elements) via AJAX. I know it is by design that JQM only loads the first page element in such a situation.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/14764732/954376). But the solution of setting data-rel='external' and data-ajax="false" doesn't work for me.

Here is my problem:
I have a multi-page A - a home page loaded by browser, it will load another single-page B from server, and it can go back to page A via a back button (data-rel='back'). Everything goes well until I tried hitting refresh on page B, now if I hit back button, page A is reloaded from server, but only the first page element is inserted into DOM, so it is broken.

I don't want to use data-rel='external' on the back button, because that way I lost the nice sliding animation for the normal case (where page B is not refreshed). What is the best way to solve this problem?

I can think of one way: add a snippet of js in page A's first page, when loaded, it checks if sibling page divs are present in DOM, if not, trigger a refresh. But this is an ugly solution. I hope there is a more elegant way (maybe a JQM upgrade?)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but [prefetch](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html) could help.